# Glassfish not started when installed via Chef Cookbook

Tags: glassfish, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to vagrant and chef. I spin up my Vm using Vagrant and provision it using Chef-solo. I add the cookbook for glassfish downloaded from opscode chef. Glassfish is installed, but not started. I have given in my vagrantfile

```
chef.add_recipe "glassfish::attribute_driven_domain"
chef.json = {
  "glassfish" => {
    "base_dir" => "/usr/local/glassfish",
    "domains_dir" => "/usr/local/glassfish/glassfish/domains",
    "domains" => {
      "domain1" => {
        "config" => {
          "domain_name" => "domain1",
          "admin_port" => 4848,
          "username" => "root",
          "password" => "admin",
          "remote_access" => true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to give more information. What operation system are you running on? What cookbook are you using? Why is the service not started? Are there any logs to look at? What happens when you SSH into your VM and try to manually start the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only called the **glassfish::attribute_driven_domain** recipe. To create the domain you also have to call the **glassfish::default** recipe.
The **glassfish::default** recipe creates the **domain.xlm** template used as base for the Glassfish domain.